# Runtime object creation in Java using Spring

Tags: java, spring

Say I have two classes, namely MyRealClass and MyMockClass, defined in Java. Both of them implements the same interface, namely MyInterface.

Now I need to instantiate an object of either class based on a condition (a variable which is available in my spring config xml file), like this:

```
if ${env} = 'A', then do, MyInterface mObj = new MyMockClass(...),
if ${env} = 'B', then do, MyInterface mObj = new MyRealClass(...),
```

How do I achieve this? Can I achieve this via conditional beans?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for something like the [`@Profile` annotation of Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles). This way you can have two definition of you bean of type `MyInterface` and load the appropriate one by passing the profile parameter at startup of your program.

Your XML would look like this:

```
<beans profile="A">
     <bean id="myMock" class="MyMockClass" />
</beans>
<beans profile="B">
     <bean id="myReal" class="MyRealClass" />
</beans>
```

Then, you have to start your application with the system property `-Dspring.profiles.active=A` or to specify it directly in the `web.xml` if you are in a web application:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.active</param-name>
    <param-value>A</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could place your bean definitions in different configuration files and import the configuration depending on your `env` variable.

in your main spring config xml you would add the following import:

```
<import resource="classpath:beans_${env}.xml" />
```

then you would have two (or more) `beans_*.xml` files (`beans_a.xml` and `beans_b.xml`)

Answer (score 0):

You can instanitate both objects on server up time and inject the object on the basis of environment using using Spring Bean factory .

```
If(env==='A'){
MyInterface mObj = SpringFactory.getBean("id defined in xml for mock clas")
}else if((env==='B'){
MyInterface mObj = SpringFactory.getBean("id defined in xml for real class")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the `Profile` concept of Spring.

Oy you can also do that by creating the two beans with `lazy-init="true"` then wrapping them in another bean, like that

```
<bean id="myClassFactory" class="MyClassFactory">
    <property name="myObject" ref="myClass${env}" />
</bean>

<bean id="myClassA" class="MyMockClass" lazy-init="true" />
<bean id="myClassB" class="MyRealClass" lazy-init="true" />
```

Then you just have to call `MyClassFactory.getMyObject()`